# How to calculate the degree of $∠FEB$ under this geometric scene

Tags: geometry, synthetic-geometry

I want to calculate the $∠FEB$ in the figure below, but I can't solve this question with [`GeometricScene`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/'GeometricScene'.html) function.

[image]

What can I do to find the answers to [these questions](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/105111160) in a general way?

```
GeometricScene[{"A", "B" -> {-1, 0}, "C" -> {1, 0}, "E", 
  "F"}, {Triangle[{"A", "B", "C"}], 
  PlanarAngle[{"B", "A", "C"}] == 20 °, 
  PlanarAngle[{"A", "B", "C"}] == 80 °, 
  PlanarAngle[{"A", "C", "B"}] == 80 °, Line[{"A", "F", "B"}],
   Line[{"A", "E", "C"}], Triangle[{"E", "B", "F"}], 
  PlanarAngle[{"E", "B", "F"}] == 20 °, 
  PlanarAngle[{"E", "C", "F"}] == 30 °}]
RandomInstance[%]
FindGeometricConjectures[%, 
  PlanarAngle[{__}] == _?NumericQ]["Conclusions"]
```

After this processing, we can get the figure:

[image]

But how to get the degree of $∠FEB$.

Comment: It's slow but it completes for me after a minute or so. I'm using Mathematica 12.0.0.

Comment: But I cant't(SimplifyChinese V12.0 )...

Comment: Please be specific about what you meant when you said "I can't".

Comment: The MMA of Simplified Chinese version 12.0 executes the above code and returns the input code as it is. I wonder if there is any better way to solve this problem.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you very much, but sometimes I can get this figure, sometimes I can't get it all the time.

Comment: For purposes of searching: this is the ["adventitious angles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%E2%80%99s_Adventitious_Angles) problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
FindGeometricConjectures[
 RandomInstance[
  GeometricScene[{"A", "B" -> {-1, 0}, "C" -> {1, 0}, "E", 
    "F"}, {Triangle[{"A", "B", "C"}], 
    PlanarAngle[{"C", "A", "B"}] == 20 °, 
    PlanarAngle[{"A", "B", "C"}] == 80 °, 
    PlanarAngle[{"A", "C", "B"}] == 80 °, 
    Line[{"A", "F", "B"}], Line[{"A", "E", "C"}], 
    Triangle[{"E", "B", "F"}], 
    PlanarAngle[{"E", "B", "F"}] == 20 °, 
    PlanarAngle[{"E", "C", "F"}] == 30 °}]]]
```

and shows angle BEF to equal 30 degrees.

Apologies for the presentation of my code. I really have no idea how everybody's presentation looks so awesome :(

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can't get the result of `PlanarAngle[{"B", "E", "F"}] == 30\[Degree]` because there are two angles that are `30\[Degree]`. By the following codes we can see that the result relevant is  `PlanarAngle[{"B", "E", "F"}] == PlanarAngle[{"E", "C", "F"}] == 30\[Degree]` :

```
GeometricScene[{"A", "B" -> {-1, 0}, "C" -> {1, 0}, "E", 
      "F"}, {Triangle[{"A", "B", "C"}], 
      PlanarAngle[{"B", "A", "C"}] == 20 \[Degree], 
      PlanarAngle[{"A", "B", "C"}] == 80 \[Degree], 
      PlanarAngle[{"A", "C", "B"}] == 80 \[Degree], Line[{"A", "F", "B"}],
       Line[{"A", "E", "C"}], Triangle[{"E", "B", "F"}], 
      PlanarAngle[{"E", "B", "F"}] == 20 \[Degree], 
      PlanarAngle[{"E", "C", "F"}] == 30 \[Degree]}];
    t = RandomInstance[%]
    FindGeometricConjectures[t]["Conclusions"]
```

So you can see why `FindGeometricConjectures[t, PlanarAngle[{__}] == _?NumericQ]["Conclusions"]` doesn't work: the out put is `_PlanarAngle == _PlanarAngle ==_` so `_PlanarAngle == _` doesn't match, and it's easy to give a general solution to this circumstances: using

```
     FindGeometricConjectures[t,Equal[_PlanarAngle..,_?NumericQ]]["Conclusions"]
```

, and it gives

```
     {PlanarAngle[{"B", "E", "F"}] == PlanarAngle[{"E", "C", "F"}] == 30 \[Degree],
     PlanarAngle[{"C", "B", "E"}] == 60 \[Degree]}
```

as we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not interested in a proof, but just want to measure the angle in a given instance of a scene:

```
scene = GeometricScene[{"A", "B" -> {-1, 0}, "C" -> {1, 0}, "E", 
   "F"}, {Triangle[{"A", "B", "C"}], 
   PlanarAngle[{"B", "A", "C"}] == 20 °, 
   PlanarAngle[{"A", "B", "C"}] == 80 °, 
   PlanarAngle[{"A", "C", "B"}] == 80 °, 
   Line[{"A", "F", "B"}], Line[{"A", "E", "C"}], 
   Triangle[{"E", "B", "F"}], 
   PlanarAngle[{"E", "B", "F"}] == 20 °, 
   PlanarAngle[{"E", "C", "F"}] == 30 °}]
instance = RandomInstance[scene]
```

The coordinates of the points can be extracted like this:

```
instance[[1, 1]]
```

> {"A" -> {1.05443*10^-16, -5.67128}, "B" -> {-1., 0.}, "C" -> {1., 0.},
> "E" -> {0.532089, -2.65366}, "F" -> {-0.652704, -1.96962}}

You can measure the angle in a number of different ways:

```
(TriangleMeasurement[{"B", "E", "F"}, {"InteriorAngle", "E"}]/N[Degree]) /. instance[[1, 1]]
```

> 30. 

```
(PlanarAngle["E" -> {"B", "F"}]/N[Degree]) /. instance[[1, 1]]
```

> 30. 

You can repeat the experiment a number of times with different instances.